# Find multiple elements of a sub-array entry

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

So, I'ld like to add a "Like" system on something I'm working on and I have a bit of trouble with it.

So my DB's table for my likes is like this :

```
========================================
|| *id* | created | user_id | post_id ||
========================================
```

I'm with with counting the number of likes for a post and all. The problem I have is I want to find if the logged user has already liked the post is is viewing so the "Like" link would become an "Unlike" link. And that's my problem. I can't manage to imagine how to do it.

Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at `Model::hasAny()` method:

```
$userHasLikedThisPost = $this->Like->hasAny(array(
    'user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id'), 
    'post_id' => $postId
));
```

Then simply set a view var and output the corresponding link.

Make a helper method in the model so its more re-usable:

```
public function hasLike($postId, $userId) {
    return $this->hasAny(array(
        'user_id' => $userId, 
        'post_id' => $postId,
    ));
}
```

Comment: Hum, it gaves me a fatal error :/ "Fatal error: Call to a member function hasAny() on a non-object in /app/Controller/PostsController.php on line 11"

Comment: Is your model called `Like`? I only assumed that - call it on whatever you named your model.

Comment: If you're in your Posts controller then your main model is Post and you need to chain it to Like via `$this->Post->Like`